# Emacs: can't find uname when attempting to connect to remote host with tramp

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp

I'm using [emacs 24.3 on OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and I'm running into some trouble using tramp to connect to remote hosts.  Every time I attempt to connect I get the following error:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for root@foo.example.com using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh -l root  -e none foo.example.com'

Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh -l root  -e none foo.example.com'
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on `foo.example.com'
Tramp: Opening connection for root@foo.example.com using ssh...done
byte-code: `echo \"`uname -sr`\"' does not return a valid Lisp expression: `sh: uname: command not found
```

The remote host in this instance is an older Fedora install, and uname exists at `/bin/uname`. I'm also getting the same error with Ubuntu 12.10 machines so I don't think it's a problem with the remote host. I've tried a bunch of different things including setting the value `tramp-remote-path` to no avail. My current tramp related config looks like:

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/bin")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/usr/bin")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/usr/local/bin")
```

I would appreciate any pointers or assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this issue was caused by a stray setting in .emacs that changed the shell settings. If you have accumulated a lot of settings, I would strongly advise you to start from the ground up instead of trying to debug your .emacs file. First make sure you can reach your host via ssh outside of emacs. Once that's working, run

```
% emacs -q
```

to start with no config file. Inside emacs, do

```
(require 'tramp)
```

and try to open a file on your remote host

```
C-xC-f /your-host-name:/path/on/your/host/file.name
```

If this works, as it did for me, great! Now you can figure out what problem in your .emacs was causing things to break. Look for anything related to sub-shells or tramp configuration variables and work from there.

If things are still broken, try adding more diagnostics for tramp

```
(setq tramp-debug-buffer t)
(setq tramp-verbose 10)
```

and inspect the output buffers. In particular, try to figure out whether you're reaching the remote host at all, or are tripping over something on the client end.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was calling this function which I added to execute latex stuff within emacs

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Sets the exec-path to the same value used by the user shell"
  (let ((path-from-shell
         (replace-regexp-in-string
          "[[:space:]\n]*$" ""
          (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -l -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
```

After playing around with my shell and homebrew I broke something and I was getting the error you describe so at the end I remove that function and by now I just have the following config for my paths

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/bin")))
```